# Android: checking if location service is enabled crashes the app

Tags: java, android, service, location

This is what I currently have running:

```
    public void GPSStatus(){
            locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            GpsStatus = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
```

For some reason when calling it and checking what it sets the predefined variable as:

```
    GPSStatus();
    if(GpsStatus == true) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
```

or even when just calling the method:

```
    GPSStatus();
```

crashes the whole app. Any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: did you add location permisiion in your manifest file

Comment: Have you add location permission in manifest file?

Comment: @ashish
@NileshRathod
I believe so, I have the following: `
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
`

Comment: What error does it showing in Error Log, Check you error log.

Comment: @DeewankshiSharma
I checked the error log but I couldn't read out the cause of the crash. Here's what the error log looks like: [link](http://i.imgur.com/RukK1oA.png)

Comment: @jit add your crash log. so it is easy to identify your problem.

Comment: What made you think you shouldn't post the error log?

Comment: @jit here it says context is null, i suggest you to pass Activity context in function GPSStautus(Context context) like this.

Comment: @DeewankshiSharma
Well.... you were right, context was null because I didn't initialize it in onCreate :D
Thank you for making me check that by bringing it out.

Comment: Welcome.......up vote highly appreciated  :)

Comment: @DeewankshiSharma
I would but it seems like upvoting requires me to have 15 reputation whilst I only have 6 at the moment, sorry about that :(

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void requestGPS_Permission() {

        String requiredPermission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
        String requiredPermission1 = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;

        // If the user previously denied this permission then show a message explaining why
        // this permission is needed
        if (getActivity().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&getActivity().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(requiredPermission1) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            GPSStatus();
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This app needs to record audio through the microphone....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            requestPermissions(new String[]{requiredPermission}, 101);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 101 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            GPSStatus();
            // This method is called when the  permissions are given
        }

    }
```

Run this code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer will depend on the SDK you are targeting, but you can use this to check that the app has the permission, because in the last versions you have to ask the user to grant them:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //do your checks
    //...
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getApplicationContext(), new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, SINGLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if you can use getApplicationContext() in the requestPermission, otherwise, just use the context of your activity